# I have a useReducer state that's an object holding an array of numbers. When I try to increment one of those numbers in the reducer, it goes up by 2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-reducer

Here's my react component and my reducer function:

```
const testReducer = (state) => {
  const newState = {...state}
  newState.counts[0] += 1

  return newState
}

function App() {
  const [countState, dispatchCount] = useReducer(testReducer, {counts: [0]})

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{countState.counts[0]}</h1>
      <button onClick={dispatchCount}>up</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When the button is clicked and the reducer is executed, I expect the count displayed in the H1 to increment by one. This happens when the button is clicked the first time, but every subsequent click increments it by 2.

This happens no matter what the count is initialized to. If the value I'm incrementing is not in an array, it works normally.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: `newState.counts[0] = += 1` isn't valid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

`newState.counts[0] = += 1` isn't valid syntax. Assuming you meant `newState.counts[0] += 1` then you are mutating the state object.

```
const testReducer = (state) => {
  const newState = {...state}
  newState.counts[0] += 1 // <-- mutates newState.counts!!

  return newState
}
```

In all likelihood this mutation is being exposed in your app by being rendered within a `React.StrictMode` component.

[StrictMode - Detecting unexpected side effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - Function component bodies
> - State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)
> - Functions passed to `useState`, `useMemo`, or **`useReducer`** <-- this

## Solution

Even though you are shallow copying state you still need to return a new `counts` array reference.

```
const testReducer = (state) => {
  const newState = {
    ...state,
    counts: [state.counts[0] + 1]
  };

  return newState;
};
```

[image: Edit i-have-a-usereducer-state-thats-an-object-holding-an-array-of-numbers-when-i-t]